# Loop and read all properties in nested objects in Javascript (Edited)

Tags: javascript

In my code, I created a object with 2 sub-objects as follows

```
 var testObject = { 
           "page":{
             "type": "ePurchase",
             "title":"Purchase confirmation"
             }, 
           "user": {
             "name": "Peter",
             "lastname": "Smith"
             }
            };
```

What I want to do is, I have an input field at the html page and once I type e.g name, the programme will loop all the attributes to see if there is any match records and match. And my idea is as follows:

```
    var input = document.getElementById('propertyName').value; 
    for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(testObject).length; i++ ) {
       for (var j=0; j < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(testObject[i]).length; j++ ) {
          if(testObject[i].getOwnPropertyNames[j] == input) { 
             console.log("The relevant input name ");
          } 
       } 
   }
```

i.e If I type name in the input, I would like to have "Peter" return.

However, I got the error "Cannot covert undefined or null to object"
How can I do so as to make it works?

Also.. as I am also a beginner in javascripts and programming.. do u guys have any idea that I can express the idea in a better way?

Many thanks for all your help in advance =)

Comment: If you wish to loop over Objects, use `for...in`

Comment: This might help: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/73755/88506

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks! I will absolutely take a look =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use the wrong objects at the wrong time.

Have a look at the console.logs here:

```js
var testObject = {
  "page": {
    "type": "ePurchase",
    "title": "Purchase confirmation"
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  }
};


var input = "Peter" // document.getElementById('propertyName').value;
var keys = Object.keys(testObject);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(keys[i])
  var test = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(testObject[keys[i]])
  console.log(test)
  for (var j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
    console.log(input,test[j],testObject[keys[i]][test[j]])
    if (testObject[keys[i]][test[j]] == input) {
      console.log("Matched record");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and also with an detailed testing procedure =) Another question: Instead of output the matched record in console log, if I want to return the value of the attributes e.g john when I input name...How can I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

> [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in original insertion order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```
var testObject = {
        "page": {
            "type": "ePurchase",
            "title": "Purchase confirmation"
        },
        "user": {
            "name": "Peter",
            "lastname": "Smith"
        }
    };
    for (var outerObj in testObject) {
        for (var innerObj in testObject[outerObj]) {
            if (testObject[outerObj][innerObj] === "Smith") { // document.getElementById('propertyName').value;
                console.log("Record matched");
            }
        }
    }
```

First try to understand what the `JavaScript object notation(JSON)` is?. `object` is simply a key value pair in `JSON`, so when we use `for..in` loop over object we can access both `key` and `value`. 
In our case `testObject` is an JavaScript object. If we iterate over this object using 'for..in' it will give us `key` like `outerObj` in our case, we just use this `key` to get value reside against this key which is also is an `object`. It means we can still iterate the resulted object using `for..in` loop and this loop again returning us a key which is `innerObj`, here we can check what values are against the `key` that retrieved from `innerObj`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand your logic and it perfectly makes sense. However can you also share in this case that how woud you call (which which command)  the inner and outer object i.e testObject and the inneroBJ i.e Page or User in the for loop?

Comment: @PakHangLeung Please refer to explanation

Comment: i see ... but at the same time can I also retrieve the value when I input the attributes i.e return "Peter" when I input name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(testObject).length; i++ ) {
var testObj = Object.keys(testObject[Object.keys(testObject)[i]])
       for (var j=0; j <testObj.length; j++ ) {
          if(testObj[j]== input) { 
             console.log("Matched record");
          } 
       } 
   }
```